# Is there an implicit version field in JPA?

Tags: jpa, eclipselink, objectdb

I'm new to JPA and have noticed that one can make use of optimistic locking by annotating a field in an entity with `@Version`. I'm just curious about whether persistence providers will create an implicit version field if there doesn't exist one before. For example the website of [objectdb](http://www.objectdb.com/java/jpa/persistence/lock#Optimistic_Locking_) states:

> "When using ObjectDB, optimistic locking is enabled by default and fully automatic."

But this seems to be vendor-specific behaviour since optimistic locking won't be enabled by default in EclipseLink, for example. So if I want to use locking (and yes, I want :-) ), am I required to create an extra attribute for all my entities? Are there any hints in the specification?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, the JPA `@Version` annotation allows you to define a version property, I assume ObjectDB just creates a this property by default.

Your own property can be an Integer, Long or Short (or their primitive equivalents), or a java.sql.Timestamp.

Most JPA providers I'm aware of only do optimistic locking if you explicitly use the `@Version` annotation.

Comment: Well, I feared that. What I actually want to achieve is to lock all entities in arbitrary queries, but without making assumptions of the state of the entity model and without knowing the actual persistence provider.

Comment: Optimistic locking doesn't actually "lock" the record, if you want a real lock you need to look at pessimistic locking.

Comment: And I think you'd be safe using `@Version` on a property of type long if you want portability.

Comment: I understand, but let's assume I don't know the entity model, but I want to set locks (more in the context of a library than my own application)

Comment: Then you could use pessimistic locking (explicitly locking records via the EntityManager).